# problem in a validation form - php

Tags: php, javascript, validation

i have a problem in my code. I have an ajax validation that calls a php file (where the data is validated).

The php returns echos like "invalidData" and in the javascript i check `if (data=="invalidData") {//something}`

The problem are the includes. Incredible thing.

```
 <?php
    include("includes/f_banco.php");
    conecta ();

    function get_post_var($var) {
        $val = $_POST[$var];
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $val = stripslashes($val);
        return $val;
    }


    $name = get_post_var('name');


    function validateName($name){
        if(strlen($name) < 4 || (empty($name))) {
            echo "invalidData";
            return false;
        }
        else {

            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='".$name."'")
            or die(mysql_error());
            $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

            if ($check2 == 0 && $name != "") {
                echo "validData";
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "invalidData";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    validateName($name);

    ?>
```

in the code above i only can check if the name is empty if i don't put the includes in the file. If i put the result is again and again different than invalidData.

The connection to the database is not made too or if is made the return is not the correct. Important: the include file is correct, i test in another example and the database is correct too.

thanks

```
Edit: **LAST VERSION**

<?php 
error_reporting(-1); 

require 'includes/f_banco1.php';

$name = $_POST["carlos"];


function validateName($name){
    if(strlen($name) < 4 || (empty($name))) {
        echo "nomeInvalido";
        return false;
    }
    else {

        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='".$name."'")
        or die(mysql_error());
        $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if ($check2 == 0 && $name != "") {
            echo "nomeValido";
            return true;
        } else {
            echo "nomeInvalido";
            return false;
        }
    }
}


validateName($name);

echo "this must appear";
?>
```

output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: carlos in C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\validation.php on line 8
nomeInvalidothis must appear
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your include file? Simply including the file wouldn't hurt anything, but if that include file is altering `$_POST['name']` then it would change the results of your other functions.

Comment: Also, you have a few redundant checks. You don't need to check for `empty($name)` because if it's empty, then its `strlen` will be 0 and will be caught by the first condition. Same with `$name != ""` in your `else` condition.

Comment: updated code with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably PHP debug 101... just do a

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
...
?>
```

And inspect the error...

Comment: He calls error reporting before the call, AFTER the include. Thanks for the (0)... typo there... meant -1.

Comment: Makes sense... php is procedural. Code will only be read after the error. `error_reporting` must be put right after `<?php` ...

Comment: man If i put the function conecta () directly in the document, the script works well!!! How it can be possible?

Comment: The problem is probably with the include (and the fact it's a relative path). Just do what I told you before to check the "real" error and you wont have to keep guessing...

Comment: i just add <?php error_reporting(-1); and none is showed in the console

Comment: None is shown in the console. May I assume you are using Firebug? Doing an Ajax call and then checking it up using Firebug? Nothing showing is a clear sign that your program is being halted at some position without throwing an error. Do `<?php error_reporting(-1); echo "this must appear"; ` and then push `echo "this must appear"; down the program flow till you identify the culprit.

Comment: Point of situation: I change the $name to this: $name = $_POST["carlos"]; and the result with the debug is: Notice: Undefined index: carlos in C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\validation.php on line 11 -------line 11 is where i have $name. i Will update the code above to the last version
nomeInvalidothis must appear

Comment: That's just a simple "notice" saying that the Array `POST` does not have the variable "carlos" inside it. Move forward.

Comment: How i can move forward? the query only works with the the function directly in the php. Require  doesn't work. Even with absolute path doesn't work.

Comment: Is require is not actually fetching the needed file... you must be pointing it to the wrong direction. Do a <?php echo getcwd() ?> to see where you are at. When I said move forward... meant that you should not waste time with that "notice".

Comment: if i do a simple <?php

include("f_banco.php");
$theclass->conecta();


echo "nomeInvalido";

?> - ---- THis is interpreted as something diferent than nomeInvalido. If i remove the include or copy paste to the file. The echo is recognized well.

Comment: solved! Incredible. I just create a new include file , copy paste the content present in the includes and now works. Thanks for you time and help. I will accept you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your query to be the following:

```
SELECT `username` FROM users WHERE `username` ='".$name."'
```

And, another question... If you already know what the username is, then why are you running a query to find the username? I assume you're just checking to see if the username exists.

Comment: It is just to debugging. your suggestion not solve the problem. If i put the includes directly in the file, all works, obviously i cant make this definitively.

Comment: Adding the quotes in the query usually does the trick for me. I was looking at your code, and it seemed as if invalidData was called if information from the query was empty.

Comment: the query works, check the database and the results now are fine. But this occurs only with the function conecta() directly in the php file (where the validations are done)